# access SpamAssassin SpamBox from command line

Tags: bash, spam, spamassassin, find

I am trying to create a CRONjob to delete spam older than x days. I can do this from the command line with *non-spam* emails by using the following script:

`find "/home/account/mail/example.com/username/cur/" -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;`

**The problem is that I also want to do this with spam email. The above script does not touch the spam.**

I think the catch may be that I am using SpamBox. I'm not sure where SpamAssassin "stores" the emails it marks as spam, hence the issue `find`ing it with the above script.

Can anyone help? Should I give this up as a fool's errand?

Note: server is collocated hosting with a cPanel. (I'm reasonably versed on the command line, but this info might be useful to you.)

Comment: Things involving cpanel are usually off-topic here, but there might be a generic answer that could work for you.  SpamAsssasin itself only gives a score to the message.  You'll need to look at how mail is routed after that to find where it goes.  Typically tagged spam is store in a "quarantine".  Are you sure it isn't already being cleaned up regularly?

Comment: It's definitely not cleaned up… it just sits in the email directory forever (I.e. can be seen in webmail). When you say I will "need to look at how mail is routed after that to find where it goes", do you mean I should look to **Dovecot** for the answer? Should I be looking into `doveadm` for the answer?

Comment: I'm hoping to bypass cPanel, btw.

Comment: `dovecot` doesn't route mail, it lets you get at the inbox, but that configuration could still be informative in this case.  When I said routing I was thinking about `sendmail` or `postfix` and there's a good chance `procmail` is involved.  Any of those paths should help you find where the spam is stored.  Recursively using `du` might work too.

Comment: @chicks I appreciate the education. I'm a front-end programmer and email routing has always been a mystery to me. I will read up on your recommendations. I will also follow up with my progress. All the best to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to say thanks to those who helped above, especially @chicks. I did eventually come up with a working solution, and I am posting that here.

I implemented the solution using a CRONjob in the cPanel; however, the solution code can be implemented in several other manners. It was similar to the code in my OP, but required delicate trial-and-error experimentation to find the correct mapping strategy. Here's how it worked out:

For an example, we have an account called "shazam". This account hosts a site called "example.com" where we have a user called "Dave". Naturally, Dave's email address is dave@example.com.

In this case, SpamAssassin routes Dave's identified junk mail to:

```
shazam
- example.com
-- dave
--- spam
```

The working command is:

```
find "/home/shazam/mail/example.com/dave/.spam/" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

The "+30" restricts the deleted emails to only those over 30 days old.

Dave also has some global email filters that route "special clients" emails into a second spam folder in a second location that is subordinate to his inbox:

```
shazam
- example.com
-- dave
--- INBOX
---- spam
```

The working command is:

```
find "/home/shazam/mail/example.com/dave/.INBOX.spam/" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

The paths may have to be varied depending upon the host's organization methods.

I post this here in case the syntax helps others to answer this quicker than I did!